# Aptana crashing on creating new ftp connetction

Tags: aptana, aptana3

After long work with no issues, Aptana started to crash every time I try to create new ftp connection.
Is this a known issue?
I am on  Linux 64 and using standalone version

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem. I'm using standalone `Aptana Studio 3 Version: 3.4.2.201308081805` with `JRE Version: 1.7.0_45 on Kubuntu 64 bit 13.10 Saucy`. Everything should be fine, but unfortunately it's not.

The problem seems to appear after upgrading the OS-Version. Aptana on the previous Kubuntu version was and still is running quite well.

My workaround:

- Install 13.04 on V-Box,
- install AptanaStudio on Guest-System,
- load workbench from host-system,
- do changes in Connection Manager and save them,
- start Aptana on host-system and the changes are there

It's not exactly what I would call a convenient way, but it works.

I hope that there will be a solution for this issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest Update Aptana 3.5.0.201312191422 fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana uses GTK themes on kde. Change the Gtk2 style from QtCurve to other because it can't render the FTP windows